# Get MMU mapping of an (emulated) ARM board

Tags: gdb, embedded, qemu, mmu

Is there a way to capture the MMU context during a breakpoint (and eventually obtain fancy picture to understand it) using QEMU console and/or GDB connected to a QEMU instance ?

Comment: just read the mmu table?